# Analyze nullability inside anonymous types with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, nullable-reference-types, microsoft.codeanalysis

Here's a piece of code I want to analyze with Roslyn:

```cs
object Method()
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  return new { First = "1", Second = rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? "2" : null };
}
```

I would like to find out the nullability of the returned properties.
I know how to find the `ReturnStatementSyntax` and its `SemanticModel`.

My problem is that C# doesn't create nullability annotations on anonymous types. The anonymous type above is `{ First: string, Second: string }`, without annotations.

My understanding is that for anonymous types the compiler uses nullability based on data-flow analysis only (correct me if I'm wrong). When hovering `Second`, VS does correctly indicate that it's nullable `string?` at this location.

Using Roslyn (`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`), how can I extract the information that the returned `First` property is non-nullable and `Second` is nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out that it does work as you'd expect.

I was fooled for a long time by a Roslyn limitation: LINQ expressions loose nullability annotations (as of April 2020) and that was my test case :(